# Searching for items in a list of sublists, and getting name of sublist the item is contained in

Tags: r

I have a list of lists in R. There are 15 sublists (a bunch of gene names) in the overall list. I want to be able to search a gene name, and have R return the name of the sublist the gene name is in.

The code below produces an object of class 'list' containing more objects of class list (e.g. elements$TwoThree).

I've tried using list.search() in multiple forms, as well as using double-brackets, etc.

```
break.venn <- list(One = dds.break1.genes.df$GENES, 
                     Two = dds.break2.genes.df$GENES, 
                     Three = dds.break3.genes.df$GENES, 
                     Four = dds.break4.genes.df$GENES)             
combs <- 
  unlist(lapply(1:length(break.venn), 
                function(j) combn(names(break.venn), j, simplify = FALSE)),
         recursive = FALSE)
names(combs) <- sapply(combs, function(i) paste0(i, collapse = ""))
str(combs)

elements <- 
  lapply(combs, function(i) setdiff(break.venn[i], break.venn[setdiff(names(break.venn), i)]))
```

EDIT: Here's what I finally did to solve all this. My goal was a list of the components of a venn diagram, and the genes that fall into each venn diagram category. Then I wanted to find out which category of the venn a specific gene falls into:

```
GOI <- "MYB90"

ItemsList <- venn(xx.1, show.plot=FALSE)
attributes <- attr(ItemsList,"intersections")
t1 <- list.search(attributes, GOI %in% .)
name <- names(t1)
cat(GOI, "is contained in", name)
```

Comment: Are the sub lists a vector/list with many elements or one long one with many names? I.e., `c(“a”, “b”, “c”)` or `c(“a, b, c”)`

Comment: If you could provide a reproducible example w/ your expected output, it would make it much easier! Depending on how your data (and what you want), you could use `rapply` or `lapply` with `%in%`, or you could use `Filter`

Comment: Is there a way to tell whether it has many elements or one long one with many names? Each gene is given a bracketed number by R, if that helps?

Comment: Great question, you could use `str(main_list_name)` or you could use `str` on one of your sublists. If it is not too long, post it as an edit. If it is too long then I'll think of another way to get the info!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had to go back and redo the whole thing. What I was attempting to do was get the components of a venn diagram, and what was in each venn category/overlap. Then used list.search to find what I wanted. I'll add my solution to my original question. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!!!